# Add paragraph with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to add a paragraph in each div having the class "text" of my HTML code. The number of div is not known in advance. To do this, I thought to use a for loop but it does not work. Would you have a solution to offer me? Thank you :)

https://jsbin.com/retanibika/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML

```
<section>
   <!-- Première div. Index [0] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>  
</section>

<section>
   <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>  
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
class AddTexte {
  constructor(){
    this.blocTexte = document.querySelectorAll('.texte');
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
  }

  texte(){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.blocTexte.length -1; i++){
      this.blocTexte[i].appendChild(this.p);
      this.p.innerHTML = "Bla bla bla"
    }
  }
}

let newAddTexte = new AddTexte();
newAddTexte.texte();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `this.blocTexte.length` instead of `this.blocTexte.length - 1` so that the loop reaches total number of `texte` elements.
- Create as many paragraph elements as `.texte` elements. You  can do so by creating  `p` inside the loop. Doing so, remove `this.p = document.createElement('p');`

  ```js
  class AddTexte {
    constructor() {
      this.blocTexte = document.querySelectorAll('.texte');
    }
    texte() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.blocTexte.length; i++) {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = "Bla bla bla"
        this.blocTexte[i].appendChild(p);
      }
    }
  }

  let newAddTexte = new AddTexte();
  newAddTexte.texte();
  ```

  ```html
  <section>
    <!-- Première div. Index [0] -->
    <div class="texte"></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
    <div class="texte"></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
    <div class="texte"></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
    <div class="texte"></div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
    <div class="texte"></div>
  </section>
  ```

---

I recommend you to go for `for ...of` loop. It is much readable and easier to maintain.

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects,
>   including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments
>   or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It
>   invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
>   value of each distinct property of the object. -
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
class AddTexte {
  constructor() {
    this.blocTexte = document.querySelectorAll('.texte');
  }
  texte() {
    for (let texte of this.blocTexte) {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "Bla bla bla"
      texte.appendChild(p);
    }
  }
}

let newAddTexte = new AddTexte();
newAddTexte.texte();
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Première div. Index [0] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Deuxième div. Index [1] -->
  <div class="texte"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create a new element for each paragraph you would like to append to the DOM.
2. You have an *off-by-one* error in your code. You should not subtract 1 from the length of the nodelist. (Unless you dont want the last div to contain the paragraph of course)

I have a working example below:

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

for (let div of texts) {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerText = "Bla bla bla";
  div.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div>no text</div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue is that you are using the same paragraph tag, so it will be moved. I would also transform the elements to an array to make it easier to iterate over them.

```
class AddTexte {

    constructor(){
        this.blocTexte = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('texte'));
      }

      texte(){
        this.blocTexte.forEach(function (div) {
          let p = document.createElement('p');
          div.appendChild(p);
          p.innerHTML = "Bla bla bla";
        });
      }
    }

    let newAddTexte = new AddTexte();
    newAddTexte.texte();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript function to get all the elements in an array, below is a sample code.

```
function getElementArray() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("texte");
  x[0].innerHTML = "Bla bla bla";
}
```

x in this case will hold array of all divs.